# Measuring chance ("risk") of being in some class

Tags: classification, statistics, prediction, survival-analysis

I don't know if this question fits better here or in statistics, but I think here is more appropriate.

I have a dataset with several companies and its features and also I have the information if they "broke" in a near future or not. I want build a model that could measure the probability of a company to break in a near future.

At first glance this seems a classification problem, yet I do not want to have a binary answer, but a number that measures the "risk" of this company to break.

Can anyone suggest me a bibliography, or maybe suggest a (class of) model(s) on this kind of problem? Is survival analysis a good way to approach this problem?

The features I have are not in a time series, though it is obtained from temporal date. There are features like chargeback rate, maturity of chargeback, number of transactions the company did in the past 3 months and its mean value and so on.

Comment: Welcome to the forum! When your $y$ is binary, you can use Logit (or related) methods to obtain a probability of belonging to class 1/0. If this is not what you need, please provide a more detailed description of the problem.

Comment: Look into ordinal regression